# XY and YZ rotations in QISKIT

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate

I noticed that QISKIT only has RZX rotation as a standard gate. Is there a simple way for me to define RYX and RYZ rotations? Why didn't they implement those rotations yet?

I need those rotations to define dipolar coupling, as in the equation below, in a two qubit quantum circuit.

$$\hat{\textbf{S}}_1 \cdot \textbf{D} \cdot \hat{\textbf{S}}_2$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that,
$R_{\sigma_i\sigma_j} = \exp(-i\frac{\theta}{2}\sigma_j \otimes \sigma_i)$ where $\sigma_i$ and $\sigma_j$ are any two single-qubit Pauli operators.

In Qiskit you can create the gate $R_{\sigma_i\sigma_j}$ as follows

```
from qiskit.opflow import I, X, Y, Z
from qiskit.opflow import PauliTrotterEvolution, Suzuki
from qiskit.circuit import Parameter
from qiskit.opflow.primitive_ops.pauli_op import PauliOp

def two_paulis_rotation(theta: Parameter, pauliOp1: PauliOp, pauliOp2: PauliOp):
    if pauliOp1 not in [I, X, Y, Z]:
        raise Exception('pauliOp1 is not one of I, X, Y, or Z')
    if pauliOp2 not in [I, X, Y, Z]:
        raise Exception('pauliOp2 is not one of I, X, Y, or Z')

    H = 0.5 * (pauliOp2 ^ pauliOp1) # Qiskit uses "little endian" bit ordering
    evolution_op = (theta * H).exp_i() # exp(-iθH)

    trotterized_op = PauliTrotterEvolution(trotter_mode = Suzuki(order = 1)).convert(evolution_op)
    circuit = trotterized_op.to_circuit()
    return circuit.to_gate()
```

And you can add the gate to your circuit as follows:

```
theta = Parameter('θ')

circ = QuantumCircuit(2)
circ.append(two_paulis_rotation(theta, Z, X), [0, 1])
```